# How to disable udp in shadowsocks or outline server without modifying Client-side code (How to modify shadowsocks server to use pure tcp (not udp))

Tags: udp, outline

My main question is in title !
I want to disable udp from shadowsocks or outline server without modifying Client-side code

(I want to disable udp only for 1 access-key )

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Android version or other version?

For my case.

I am using v2ray to set up ShadowSock Service.
ShadowSocks often supporting both of TCP & UDP for inbound Traffic.
perhaps you may also change the config.json.

```
 {
        "protocol": "shadowsocks",
        "port": 31524,
        "settings": {
            "method": "aes-256-gcm",
            "password": "Your Password",
            "network": "**tcp,udp**",
            "level": 1,
            "ota": false
        }
    }
            //include_socks
            //include_mtproto
            //include_in_config
            //
    ],
    "outbounds": [
```

change the tcp,udp to tcp. the server will accept tcp traffic and it worked.
Please reference this link : https://www.v2ray.com/en/configuration/protocols/shadowsocks.html

Comment: No I want to modify server side to disable udp for one access key !